# create jabber ID on Server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I have configured BOSH connection manager i.e. Punjab on my server

so far i was using **register.jabber.org** to ***create jabber account*** , now i want to create my own JID for my users over my server so can anyone tell me how would i do that ?

so far i was using following end point for jabber bosh service

http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind
to run example of **Wrox Professional XMPP programming with Javascript and Jquery**

if you want more information then please do ask , rather then closing a question

i am using strophe as a javascript client 
http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind as BOSH_SERVICE_URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create an account on ejabberd you can either:

1. Locate ejabberdctl and do:

   ./ejabberdctl register user_id domain password
2. Login to http://localhost:5280/admin as your ejabberd admin and register a user from the web ui.
3. Enable web registration on ejabberd and visit http://localhost:5280/register
4. If you want to do that through javascript you need to implement the Add User command from [XEP-133](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html) with Strophe.

Answer (score 0):

to create a jabber ID account , you need to run ejabberd server and fire on

http://www.mydomain.com:5280/register/

and click on **Register a Jabber account** to create jabber ID on your server